# Slim Blog and HTML

Tags: html, twig, slim

So I made a simple, lightweight blog with Slim and Twig, and everything works perfectly except that my recent posts appear *below* the one before. Like blog post one is always at the top. The info is being pulled from a variable.

my php (view) file looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

<h1>Posts</h1>

{% if posts is empty %}
    <p>
        No posts yet.
    </p>
{% else %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <h2><a href="{{ urlFor('posts.show', {'postId': post.id}) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p>{{ post.body[:50] }}</p>
            <div class="author">
                <p>By: {{ post.author }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

EDIT: The query:

```
$posts = $app->db->query("
        SELECT
        posts.*,
        CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS author
        FROM posts
        LEFT JOIN users
        ON posts.user_id = users.id
    ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Any answers appreciated.

Comment: What is the order of the posts in the variable `posts`? It seems you might want to reverse the array.

Comment: What is the query that you use to populate the `posts` variable?

Comment: reverse the array or iterate from end to start. something like "for i=posts.length, i--, i==0" (not sure about php syntax, hope you will get it. ; ) )

Comment: You need to add a ORDER BY clause on your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create an if statement such as `{% if post.author = "" %}` and could not get it to work. I looked at your code and tried `{% if post is empty %}`. That does precisely what I need it to.